# Error in read.table: line 150428 did not have 35 elements

Tags: r, read.table

I know this has already been answered, but I did not understand most of the solutions.

I am using `read.table(file.txt,sep = ';', header = T)'` to load a table with 35 columns and a really large number os rows, but R keeps returning me this error:

```
 Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
    line 150428 did not have 35 elements
```

I tried opening the table on Excel and there wasn't anything wrong on those lines.

What could I do to fix this?
Thank you

EDIT: I have tried using `fill = T`, but ir returns me a lot of warnings.

```
 In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
14: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
15: In precision(x) : NaNs produced
```

I think thaat happens because I try to read the table inside a function that does other calculations.

EDIT 2: There a lot of `#` in the dataset. I've read that this could be a problem. However, other files that I have used had these as well and there was no problem at al..

Comment: Try with `fill=TRUE` in `read.table`

Comment: @akrun I have tried, but it returns me a lot of warnings.

Comment: What kind of warnings?